How can I manage a model with 40+ editable field in flutter and BLoC
I'm currently developping an ERP application but I'm quite new to BLoC state management. I'm mostly a back-end  developper, so maybe I'm doing things wrong.
I have a customer model that have 40+ properties that can be edited by the user. I have a DetailCustomerBloc to manage my object.
I need to know what is the best way to manage the modification of my model with BLoC. Do I have to create 1 event per editable property ? Or there is an other way to take care of the state of the modified object ?
Do I have to create a form that encapsulate my widgets in my page and pass the key to all the textformfield ? Or can I use only textfield ? Today I only use a TextField with a TextEditingController inside a custom textfield that is used for all my properties.
Thanks for your help.
EDIT : My app is a windows app and my customer model is like an aggregate root that contains multiple entities/model in it.

40+ TextFileds are too much, you may categorize and separate those into diff screen  and the same patterns apply for creating models with relation, and theses models will be used on Bloc's state.  you can find more on Database design/ Design Pattern

@Md.YeasinSheikh Yeah of course, my customer model is like a agregate root of lots of different entities but what you say is that I may create multiple subbloc that may interact with the "aggregate bloc" ?

Use BlocSelector, although we have the option to use BlocBuilder, it can be costly as it rebuilds the entire form widget every time a TextFormField is changed. https://medium.com/@azharbinanwar/flutter-form-validation-with-bloc-b46a1ced63c2
But my favorite way is using GlobalKey.

Create custom form widget from stateful widget and remove underscore symbol from state class name, to turn private into public class. Because public class allow you to call widget state from anywhere.

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextField({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => MyTextFieldState();
}

class MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  late Color _borderColor;
  late Color _labelColor;
  String? _errorText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initial();
    super.initState();
  }

  void initial() {
    _errorText = null;
    _borderColor = Colors.grey;
    _labelColor = Colors.black;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void showError(String errorText) {
    _errorText = errorText;
    _borderColor = Colors.red;
    _labelColor = Colors.red;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: _labelColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (_errorText != null)
          Text(
            _errorText!,
            style: TextStyle(color: _borderColor),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Inside your screen, define global keys from state class

final nameKey = GlobalKey<MyTextFieldState>();
final passwordKey = GlobalKey<MyTextFieldState>();


Assign the keys to the designed widget

MyTextField(
  key: nameKey,
  label: 'Name',
  ...
),
MyTextField(
  key: passwordKey,
  label: 'Password',
  ...
),


Call function or variable from the state

nameKey.currentState?.showError('Min 10 chars');
nameKey.currentState?.initial();
passwordKey.currentState?.showError('Atleast 1 special chars');

